# Adding an ID to a dictionary that has a string + list <string>

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a image + imagename (that I use as a button) and a ID in my database that I wish to work with.

Right now I recieve the matching images and names together just like this (I have done the layout in XAML):

```
   IMAGE          IMAGE          IMAGE
NAME(BUTTON)   NAME(BUTTON)   NAME(BUTTON)
```

And as I have worked with an dictionary  I cannot add the ID in there because it is alrdy taken by image + imagename.

What I ultimately want to do is when you click the imagename (that is a button) I want to push the image with me (that currently works) but also the ID that does not currently fit.

I have changed the dictionary from "string, string" to "string,List, string" as a first step but I am not quite sure where to go from here.

This is my current code:

```
public Dictionary <string,List<string>> imageList = new Dictionary <string,List<string>> (); 

//public Dictionary <string,string> imageList = new Dictionary <string, string> ();
```

^thats what I had before, but as you can see it has been replaced by a list instead

```
string theID;

async void loadImages ()
{
var getImages = await phpApi.getImages ();

foreach (var theitems in getImages ["results"])
{
    imageList.Add(
      theitems ["Photo"].ToString(), //this is the Photo I get from the db
      theitems ["PhotoName"].ToString(), //the photoname
      //theitems ["ID"].ToString() and this is the ID.
    );

}

foreach (var key in imageList.Keys) { //this is part of the layout. And I have the clickedfunction below where I try to send the Image, name + id.

    var inner = new StackLayout();

    var image = new Image ();
    image.Source = key;
    image.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;

    var button = new Button ();
    button.Text = imageList [key];

    inner.Children.Add(image);
    inner.Children.Add(label);
    myStack.Children.Add (inner);

    button.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new OtherProfilePage 
   (image.Source, button.Text, theID)); //I want to add the correct ID in here

    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Updated the code, so how do I add a ID + something else in a list and still keep the current layout?

Comment: The proposed duplicate _might_ be relevant. I'm not sure, because it's not really clear what you're asking, or even if you understand how a dictionary works. In the code you've shown, you are adding a _single_ key/value pair to the dictionary, where the key is the `...["Photo"].ToString()` object and the value is the `...["PhotoName"].ToString()` object. The dictionary allows easy mapping _from_ the "photo" _to_ the "photo name". It's not clear how "id" relates to any of this.

Comment: Please fix your question so that it states precisely what you want the code to do, given specific inputs. Provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you are doing, and make sure you've explained _exactly_ what it is you want that code to do.

Comment: Sry about that, adjusted the code a bit so it got a bit messy. Updated the post now with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to use a `Tuple<string, string>`. You could also define a custom class to store your values (and have better names than `.Item1`, `.Item2`, etc), but the Tuple is going to be quicker to write.

```
public List<Tuple<string, string, string>> imageList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>> ();
```

Populating the list:

```
async void loadImages ()
{
    var getImages = await phpApi.getImages ();
    foreach (var img in getImages ["results"]) {
        imageList.Add(
            Tuple.Create(
                img["Photo"].ToString(),
                img["PhotoName"].ToString(),
                img["ID"].ToString()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Using the list:

```
foreach (var img in imageList) {
    var inner = new StackLayout();
    var image = new Image ();
    image.Source = img.Item1;
    image.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;
    var button = new Button ();
    button.Text = img.Item2;
    inner.Children.Add(image);
    inner.Children.Add(label);
    myStack.Children.Add (inner);
    button.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
        var pg = new OtherProfilePage(img.Item1, img.Item2, img.Item3);
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync (pg);
    };
}
```

Comment: Very good solution, thanks! What is the difference If I decide to do it with a custom class? Only better names or is there something else to it?

Comment: The main difference would be code readability since you could choose what the names of those item properties are. A custom class would also have slightly different performance/memory characteristics, but not enough worth worrying about for this case.